# Getting weird error when concatenating template-literals

Tags: javascript, html, dom, template-literals

I am trying to build a javascript script that will right my header to my html page so I don't have to update every one of my pages when I make a change. I learned that template literals can hold html code in variables so I started using that. I am having an error pop up in VS Code when I use ternary operators however. It says that I'm missing a ).

I've check the whole template literal for any missing parenthesis.

```
var html = `<div id="branding">
    <h1><span class="btop">JoJo</span> <span class="bbottom">Studios</span></h1>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li`+(page=="home" ? ` class="current><a href="#">Home</a>"` : `><a href="../">Home</a>`)+`</li>
        <li`+(page=="games" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href=`+(page=="games" ? `"./"` : (page=="home" ? `"games/"` : `"../games/"`)+`>Games</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href=`+(page=="games" ? `"` : (page=="home" ? `"games/` : `"../games/`)+`jojobananacatch.html">JoJo Banana Catch</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li`+(page=="play" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`><a href=`+(page=="home" ? `"play/"` : `"../play/"`)+`>Play</a></li>
        <li`+(page=="videos" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`><a href=`+(page=="home" ? `"videos/"` : `"../videos/"`)+`>DevLogs & More</a></li>
        <li`+(page=="about" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`><a href=`+(page=="home" ? `"about/"` : `"../about/"`)+`>About</a></li>
        <li`+(page=="contact" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`><a href=`+(page=="home" ? `"contact/"` : `"../contact/"`)+`>Contact</a></li>
        <li`+(page=="account" ? ` class="current"` : ``)+`><a href=`+(page=="home" ? `"account/account.php?account_forward=0"` : `"../account/account.php?account_forward=0"`)+`>Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>`;
```

The output should just be a string that I can insert into the document. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part inside `dropdown` class is where the problem is, you are using apparently two nested ternary operators but there's only one closed parenthesis.

Change

```
<a href=`+(page=="games"
           ? `"./"`
           : (page=="home"
              ? `"games/"`
              : `"../games/"`)+`>Games</a>
```

to

```
<a href=`+(page=="games"
           ? `"./"`
           : (page=="home"
              ? `"games/"`
              : `"../games/"`))+`>Games</a>
```

and the same for the second instance.

By the way you can also use directly expressions inside template (that's the whole point of templates).

This is done using the `${...}` syntax that is possibly easier to read in some cases than closing and reopening the template. For example:

```
let s = "World";
console.log(`Hello, ${s+"."}`)
```

logs `Hello, World.`

Comment: Exactly, or else it wouldn't be template literals and just basic string concatenation and no need for back ticks.

Comment: @RafaelRocha: another advantage of template string is verbatim newlines and the ability to use both single and double quotes without escaping. Sometimes they're useful even without any expression.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has bugged me for hours! I totally forgot that I had a nested ternary operator.

Comment: Is using the ${} syntax similar to $”” or string.format in c#? If anyone knows c# here.

Comment: @JoJoStudiosOfficial: Yes, it's the same, including the fact that the template is not a simple string substitution done at runtime, but requires an examination at compile time because a template string can capture variables when used inside a closure.

Answer (score 2):

Although this has already been answered, (missing closing round bracket for nested ternary) I feel you may find benefit using [string interpolation with template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). By doing this you may remove all the concatenation inside of your string (which is one of the main advantages of using template literals as opposed to regular strings).

```js
let page = 'play';
let html = `<div id="branding">
    <h1><span class="btop">JoJo</span> <span class="bbottom">Studios</span></h1>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li ${(page==="home" ? `class="current><a href="#">Home</a>"` : `><a href="../">Home</a>`)}</li>
        <li ${(page==="games" ? `class="current"` : ``)}>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href=${(page==="games" ? `"./"` : (page==="home" ? `"games/"` : `"../games/"`))}>Games</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href=${(page==="games" ? `"` : (page==="home" ? `"games/` : `"../games/`))}jojobananacatch.html">JoJo Banana Catch</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li ${(page==="play" ? ` class="current"` : ``)}><a href=${(page==="home" ? `"play/"` : `"../play/"`)}>Play</a></li>
        <li ${(page==="videos" ? ` class="current"` : ``)}><a href=${(page==="home" ? `"videos/"` : `"../videos/"`)}>DevLogs & More</a></li>
        <li ${(page==="about" ? ` class="current"` : ``)}><a href=${(page==="home" ? `"about/"` : `"../about/"`)}>About</a></li>
        <li ${(page==="contact" ? ` class="current"` : ``)}><a href=${(page==="home" ? `"contact/"` : `"../contact/"`)}>Contact</a></li>
        <li ${(page==="account" ? ` class="current"` : ``)}><a href=${(page==="home" ? `"account/account.php?account_forward=0"` : `"../account/account.php?account_forward=0"`)}>Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>`;
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how template strings work at all in Javascript (ES6 >).

Don't forget that the + won't actually concatenate the result nor have logic expression inside of it. You have to use this `${...}` to surround your js expression so that their results are immediately converted to string.

**Example**

```js
var html = `<li ${page=="home" ? '"class="current><a href="#">Home</a>':'<a href="../">Home</a>'}</li>`;
```

That's how you would use template string ( inserting logic inside of strings).
Consider also extracting the contents that you are returning in the ternary into their own separate variables. Makes for better reading.

**Example**

```js
const currentPageLink = 'class="current"><a href="#">Home</a>';
const previousPageLink = '<a href="../">Home</a>';

// and then following the example above

const html = `<li ${page==="home" ? currentAnchor: previousPageLink}</li>`;
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can very much concatenate template literals in JS. They come with two main benefits, string interpolation and multi-line values without the use of concatenation. This is valid: ```console.log(`Hello` + ` ` + `World!`);```

Comment: Wasn't saying that it's incorrect in its totality but the reason template literals exist isn't  so that you can just avoid escaping quotes or pass in new lines freely. What you mentioned isn't a template literal. It's just string concatenation with backticks.

Comment: [mdn is under the impression that it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Template_literals). Furthermore, `"+ won't actually concatenate"` is false.